# If I turn into a Gas Spore as a druid (Circle of the Seedling 5e homebrew) and use Death Burst, do I die?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, homebrew, wild-shape

In [Circle of the Seedling](https://dnd-5e-homebrew.tumblr.com/image/133953037260) 5e homebrew you can use Wild Shape to transform into a plant creature. If I turn into a Gas Spore, will I die upon using Death Burst or will it simply be the same as having your HP drop to 0 in Wild Shape?

Comment: I think this is now answerable within the extent of homebrew material, using logical assumptions, given the link. It should probably have a homebrew tag?

Comment: Related: [Can I employ Relentless Endurance while in Wild Shape?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67889)

Comment: For those considering an answer, nothing in that homebrew looks to override the standard wild shape features, beyond forms taken.

Answer (score 16):

This is the danger in using homebrew material. The creator does not typically have the benefit of an editorial staff or design team to truly vet the material before play. Also, the playtesting sample size is so small as to be almost non-existent. Because of this, homebrew material often requires on-the-fly modification or adjudication.

We can still apply some basic rules, although it would ultimately have to come down to DM adjudication. Let us proceed under the assumptions of the homebrew. There is nothing in the description of the Plant Wild Shape ability to suggest it works differently than ordinary Wild Shape upon the shape being brought to 0 HP. In the absence of specific, we must assume general.

When the gas spore drops to 0 HP two things must happen:
1) the gas spore explodes into spores. It is not only dead, it is gone. It has ceased to exist.
2) The druid reverts to humanoid form, taking whatever leftover damage might be involved.

If the gas spore disappears first, there is nothing left to turn back into a druid. If the gas spore reverts to druid form, there is nothing left that can explode. It's a binary choice.

Since the reversion to druid rule of Wild Shape normally circumvents any rules about death (the beast forms get no death saves and do not die), we should assume that the gas spore's explosion ability should come second. This is further reinforced by the fact that it would be irretrievable character death otherwise (no body), and no fun to play.

The most playable answer would be to have the spore revert to druid without triggering the explosion. The lesson here is to be very careful with homebrew and don't be surprised or disappointed if you run into problems when interacting with the official rules.

Comment: Thank you. Looking at what you've written this relates to another question I just posted. If you are in fact the spores the Gas Spore explodes into, maybe those two options you listed upon using Death Burst can be tied together in what I ask in the other question. I do see the danger in homebrew, I've seen solid answers leading to different conclusions. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

## If you die as a gas spore, you probably die altogether.

The gas spore trait "death burst" states:

> The gas spore explodes when it drops to 0 hit points.

Since you exploded you cannot reform into the druid you were before. This is backed up as it relates to this [rules answer](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-july-2016)

> **reduced to 0 hit points by disintegrate? Does the druid simply leave beast form?** The druid turns to dust, since the spell disintegrates you the instant you drop to 0 hit points.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the homebrew that changed that feature of wild shape, in terms of revert to form at 0, but maybe by use of that text it is an overwrite.  Tough one to parse.  It was wild shape that rendered the druid into the spore form.  It's an interesting question, and I'll only point out that disintegrate is a high level spell, and seems to be a slight reach to use as a comparison point. (though not altogether a bad parallel, given the description of the HB effect).

Comment: @Korvin the level of the spell is meaningless. Both effects destroy the individual so the ruling is the same.

Comment: I think a possible difference is that disintegrate both deals the damage and does the turn-to-dust at 0 hp; meanwhile the Gas Spore is brought to 0 hp by something separate from the explosion ability. Not being able to avoid the effect of the spell that killed you makes sense; it may or may not follow that being damage to 0 hp makes the separate explosion unavoidable. I think that difference means another step of reasoning is needed to ensure or disprove the connection, in a way that is not necessary for Disintegrate.

Answer (score 6):

The druid text about ending Wild Shape due to damage says:

> You automatically revert if you fall Unconscious, drop to 0 hit points, or die.

. . . and . . .

> if you revert as a result of Dropping to 0 Hit Points, any excess damage carries over to your normal form

It says nothing about the creature exploding what might happen if the creature has an effect that occurs on its death.

The Gas Spore text for Death Burst says:

> **Death Burst.** The gas spore explodes when it drops to 0 hit points.

I think this is in DM ruling territory. I don't think exploding is necessarily a problem for the druid, any more than being dismembered or other massive damage an animal would take on a typical kill, which happens to most other forms the druid could take. This comes down somewhat to visualisation - some people might imagine the creature is not mortally wounded, and instead the druid becomes fatigued by battle and has to drop the transformation; I tend to think of the creature as a spirit form that is disrupted by the last blow, then the druid re-appears in its place when this temporary form is actually slain.

My thoughts: A gas spore has 1 hit point, and is easy to hit. The whole point of the transformation would be to get a moderately low amount of explosion damage done, and the druid would likely take a fair amount of pass-through damage after the 1 hit point from the spore. Also, any child gas spores could be a problem for the Druid and companions later (they are not automatically friendly just because the Druid can communicate with them). So, unless there are any other exploits possible or intended, this seems reasonable and fun transformation.

A harsher ruling, that might also be appropriate if there is some onward loophole that the druid wants to take advantage of, could be to have the druid taking damage and effects from the explosion in addition to any nearby creatures.

Comment: Well you start by buying a dozen cattle and penning them in.  Then you wild shape into a gas sport, get hit by a dart, explode, poisoning the cattle.  Split the poisoned cattle from the healthy ones when they get sick 10 or so hours later, and place them in a spot where you want a bunch of gas spores.  Each cow exposed produces 3 adult gas spores in about 10 days and 40% of the exposed cows survive.  Any creature with significantly more than 10 HP can do (unless you rule that creatures killed by the gas spore explosion also produce baby gas spores)

Comment: @Yakk: Maybe. That's going to require some investment in containment for the gas spores, and effectively is downtime prep taking many days and careful planning. The product is monsters that cannot be reasoned with (INT 1) and their only motivation is to spread the infection in all directions. It would be quite situational where a large number of gas spores is a useful resource. Also, if the players do have any means to "herd" gas spores, then they only need to find one or two naturally and after that probably don't need the druid at all for the same spore farm.